# Gradle Project Sync failed, How to solve?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am getting error of Gradle Project sync failed. Basic functionality(editing,debugging) will not work properly

Here is the error

```
Error:(28, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_29zadyxffug4w4nfov6vkui3p$_run_closure3@7ad0dcc3] on root project 'Happybirthday1' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Happybirthday1\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Comment: Post your code, we can't help you without it

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply Android application plugin at the top of app level Gradle file, like this:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

,as this plugin identifies your code as an Android application and configures properties in android block in app level Gradle file for your application

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
}
dependencies {
    compile files('app/libs/junit-4.12-JavaDoc.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

In your `build.gradle`

and take care, shouldn't be on `module/build.gradle`